# How to do a basic URL rewrite with mod_rewrite

Tags: php, html, apache, .htaccess, web

I don't understand why but when I use this:

```
#RewriteRule ^/?r/(.*)$ /index.php?n=$1 [L]
```

to rewrite `mysite.com/r/somewhat` to `mysite.com/index.php?r=somewhat`
the site work.

But if I use this:

```
#RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ /index.php?name=$1 [L]
```

to rewrite `mysite.com/somewhat` to `mysite.com/index.php?r=somewhat`,
my site stop working.

I don't understand why. Someone can help me?

How can I rewrite `mysite.com/somewhat` to `mysite.com/index.php?r=somewhat`?

Comment: if you want `?r=somewhat`, then why are you rewriting to `?n=$1`? `n` is NOT the same as `r`.

Answer (score 1):

Your 2nd rule will cause infinite looping since target URI `/index.php?r=somewhat` also matches `.*`. Eventually it causes 500 internal server error.

To fix you need to avoid rewriting files and directories using `RewriteCond` like this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^/?(.+)$ /index.php?r=$1 [L,QSA]
```